# Google Sheets Script: Getting values from each range in a rangelist in the same variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get ranges from two different parts of the sheet and get their values to paste onto another sheet. The method I'm using works for the first range but not the next. I need values from both ranges to remain in the same variable since I need to filter it later.

```
var fromsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var fromval = fromsh.getRangeList(['A3170:O', 'Y3170:Y']).getRanges()
  var values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < fromval.length; i++){
    values = [].concat(values, fromval[i].getValues());
  }
  tosh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  tosh.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

The error shown is: 
The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 15.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to put the values from the range of `A3170:O` and `Y3170:Y`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Issue:

In your script, the number of columns is different between `A3170:O` and `Y3170:Y`. By this, an error occurs at `tosh.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)`.

### Solution:

In order to avoid above issue, how about the following modifications?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script was modified using Spreadsheet service. Pleas modify as follows.

From:

```
var values = [];
for(var i = 0; i < fromval.length; i++){
  values = [].concat(values, fromval[i].getValues());
}
```

To:

```
var obj = fromval.reduce(function(o, r) {
  var v = r.getValues();
  if (o.cols < v[0].length) o.cols = v[0].length;
  o.values = [].concat(o.values, v);
  return o;
}, {cols: 0, values: []});
var values = obj.values.map(function(e) {
  return e.length == obj.cols ? e : e = [].concat(e, Array.apply(null, new Array(obj.cols - e.length)).map(function(e) {return ""}));
});
```

- Retrieve the max column number, and the length of each element of array is adjusted by adding `""`. Then, the values are put to the Spreadsheet.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, your script was modified using Sheets API. Pleas modify as follows. Before you run this script, please enable Sheets API at [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

From:

```
tosh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
tosh.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

To:

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: values}, id, "Sheet1!A1", {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
```

- When Sheets API is used, the values can be put without adjusting the length of each element.
- When you use this, please set `id`.

### References:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

From [TheMaster's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323180/google-sheets-script-getting-values-from-each-range-in-a-rangelist-in-the-same/57323971?noredirect=1#comment101138982_57323971), I added one more sample script. In this sample script,

The values from the range `A3170:O` and `Y3170:Y` are summed for the column direction. For example, `A3170:O3170 and Y3170`.

For this situation, please modify as follows.

#### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, your script was modified using Spreadsheet service. Please modify as follows.

From:

```
values = [].concat(values, fromval[i].getValues());
```

To:

```
var temp = fromval[i].getValues();
values = i === 0 ? temp : values.map(function(e, i) {return [].concat(e, temp[i])});
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but OP probably wanted the rows to be stacked horizontally rather than vertically i.e., A3170:O3170,Y3170 or A3170:Y3170 excluding P3170:W3170. I'm just guessing though.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. When I checked OP's question again, I would like to agree with your suggestion. So I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? I hope that OP's solution is included in these samples.

Comment: Great``````````​``````````

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks a lot. I updated for more simple modification.